# Metadata deplyment with Java

Tags: deployment-api, zip

I'm trying to use java tool for deployment and seems I having issue with creating zip file.I wrote function  that receive list of files path and build ZIP folder with them.

Issue is when I deploy the zip file, it only running test classes. The deplyment components show 0/0.
So I tried the following - 
-unzip all the files from the zip that created by code. 
-Zip the files manually to other zip (by mouse right click)
With the new zip then java process is working. Therefore I assume there is something wrong with the way I creating the ZIP file.

Any suggestion?

```
public void createZIP(ArrayList<String> files, String zipFileName){

        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> m_type_childs = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        //First loop get all relevant types
        for(String fileURL : files){

            String fileAfterBase = fileURL.substring(fileURL.indexOf("src") + 4);

            String fileFolder = fileAfterBase.substring(0, fileAfterBase.indexOf("\\"));

            String fileName = fileAfterBase.substring(fileAfterBase.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, fileAfterBase.lastIndexOf(".")); 

            String sfType = Params.folder_SFType_Map.get(fileFolder);

            //For Classes/Pages/Triggers/Components should ignore the metadata-xml file when building the package.xml
            if((sfType.equals("ApexClass") || sfType.equals("ApexComponent") || sfType.equals("ApexPage") || sfType.equals("ApexTrigger"))
                    && (fileURL.endsWith("meta.xml"))){
                continue;
            }

            if(! m_type_childs.containsKey(sfType)){
                m_type_childs.put(sfType, new ArrayList<>());
            }

            m_type_childs.get(sfType).add(fileName);
        }

        //Build XML file
        String xmlComponentTypes = "";

        for(String type : m_type_childs.keySet()){
            String membersContent = "";

            for(String component : m_type_childs.get(type)){
                membersContent += "<members>" + component + "</members>";
            }

            xmlComponentTypes += "<types>" + membersContent + "<name>" + type + "</name></types>";
        }


        String xmlFull ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+
                "<Package xmlns=\"http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata\">"+
                xmlComponentTypes +
                "<version>" + Params.properties.getProperty("PACAKGE_API") + ".0</version>"+
                "</Package>";

        //Build ZIP File

        //For writing to ZIP
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ZipOutputStream zos = null;

        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(Params.properties.getProperty("ZIP_FILES_FOLDER") + "\\" + (zipFileName.endsWith(".zip") ? zipFileName : zipFileName + ".zip"));
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            FileInputStream in = null;
            int len;

            //Add the pacakge.xml file
            File pacakgeXMLFile = new File(MANIFEST_FILE);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(pacakgeXMLFile);
            fw.write(xmlFull);
            fw.close();

            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("unpackaged\\" + MANIFEST_FILE);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            in = new FileInputStream(MANIFEST_FILE);

            while ((len = in .read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();


            //Second loop - add the files to ZIP
            for(String fileURL : files){

                String fileAfterBase = fileURL.substring(fileURL.indexOf("src") + 4);

                String fileFolder = fileAfterBase.substring(0, fileAfterBase.indexOf("\\"));

                String fileName = fileAfterBase.substring(fileAfterBase.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1); 

                //Add to ZIP file
                ZipEntry componentEntry = new ZipEntry("unpackaged\\" + fileFolder + File.separator + fileName);
                zos.putNextEntry(componentEntry);
                try {
                    in = new FileInputStream(fileURL);
                    while ((len = in .read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }
            }

            zos.closeEntry();
            System.out.println("Folder successfully compressed");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                zos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: what's a structure inside? Please, check what option singlePackage. In case if that is true, then folder structure should be /src/..., otherwise is should be somepackage/src/... inside zip

Comment: Hi structure is in the zip folder 'unpackaged', and inside there is pacakge.xml file + folder per each type (classes, pages, etc....).  I think the structure is fine, as if I unzip the file that generated, and zip it again manually, then it's working.

Comment: can you share an example of zip file? with some dummy metadata?

Comment: How can I upload zip file to my comment?

Comment: you can not, upload it somewhere overcloud and share by link

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using solution in this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743773/how-can-i-make-my-java-generated-zip-file-identical-to-a-winzip-generated-one

Using org.apache.commons.compress.archivers for compressing the zip, instead of java java.util.zip and this is working.

Don't know why exacly, but I can see the properties in the zip are different when generating with each of the libararies.